# Collapse All in TextMate

Tags: textmate

Is there a way to collapse all the functions in a given php file in TextMate?

For example I have two methods:

```
function index() {
    //Sample code   
}

function beforeFilter() {
    //Sample Code
}
```

I would like to be able to issue a command where all the methods will collapse to:

```
function index() { ...

function beforeFilter() { ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Via the menu:

**View > Toggle foldings at Level > All levels**

[image]

or shortcut:

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>

Comment: Only problem is that this also folds every if, else, etc. *inside* the functions as well... is there a way to only fold the top-level functions?

Comment: Best way to do this is to collapse at all levels, then COMMAND + ALT + click the orange "collapsed" circle-arrow of the function you're looking at. This'll expand all levels, of just that one function, while all others will be collapsed still.