# Collapse all PHP functions in TextMate

Tags: coding-style, textmate, folding

I'm a bit anal about how I fold and organize my code in TextMate, and one issue that continually bothers me about TextMate's code folding behavior is that, with PHP, if I have a file with a bunch of functions, and I just want to fold all the functions (but not their contents), I have to click on each function and hit F1 (or click the little folding button in the line indicator).

I found [Collapse All in TextMate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376696/collapse-all-in-textmate), which is okay, but less than ideal, since folding all levels of code means that every if, else, while, etc. statement inside every function will also be folded, meaning I have to keep klicking or hitting F1 while I work through a function.

Is there any way to make TextMate recognize all functions inside a PHP file as 'level 1' so when I choose 'Toggle foldings at Level: 1', the functions are collapsed (but nothing inside)?

Right now, if I do that, only the first function in the entire file is collapsed. If I do level 4, the second function is collapsed (I'm not sure why this is so... all my functions are indented exactly the same... could it be that I use spaces instead of tabs to indent what's inside a function?).

Here are my start and stop markers (defaults) as defined in the Bundle Editor:

```
foldingStartMarker = '(/\*|\{\s*$|<<<HTML)';
foldingStopMarker = '(\*/|^\s*\}|^HTML;)';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just FYI, I've recorded a macro of me finding the regex '^function ', then pressing the right arrow key, then pressing F1 (to fold the function), and I've set that macro to a keyboard shortcut.

It's not as awesome as just folding everything at once, but now when I open a huge file with hundreds of functions, I can hit my key combo a bunch of times, and all the functions get folded :)

[**Edit:** I've worked a bit more at fixing this (for me), and since I don't want to fold comment blocks, but *do* want to fold functions (for Drupal module files and such), I've changed the following two lines in the PHP language syntax bundle (in Textmate's bundle editor):

```
foldingStartMarker = '(/\*|\{\s*$|<<<HTML)';
foldingStopMarker = '(\*/|^\s*\}|^HTML;)';
```

to:

```
foldingStartMarker = '(\{\s*$|<<<HTML)';
foldingStopMarker = '(^\s*\}|^HTML;)';
```

So, it's working pretty well for me now. Woot!]